# Where to find Gradle Distributions in Windows?

Tags: android, windows, gradle, build

I want to know the path of the **Gradle Distributions** in **Windows**.

For example, when I change the `distributionUrl` in the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file, it downloads a new distribution from `gradle`.

I want to know where it downloads to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Gradle Distributions** in **Windows** are located in the following path:

```
C:\Users\your_username\.gradle\wrapper\dists
```

Where `your_username` is the name of the current windows user.